# how to creat series of numbers (format) starting with zero in for loop

Tags: python-3.x

for loop need to print numbers (not in a string format) like 
`05 06 07 08 09 10 11`

For example:

```
print(format(5, '02d'))
```

Output:

```
'05'
```

I need to generate numbers (not string) in for loop

```
for i in range(int(format(5, '02d')),10):
    print(i)
```

The following code is printing `5 6 7 8 9` instead `05 06 07 08 09`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try something like below:

```
for i in range(5,10):
    print(format(i, '02d'))
```

or

```
for i in range(5,10):
    print('%02d' % i)
```

Output:

```
05
06
07
08
09
```

Comment: I need to supply this value to recursive file generting                                                df = pd.read_csv('situ_201709'+str(i)+'_v13_r04.tab'). i needs to take the value directly.

Comment: why don't you use `df = pd.read_csv('situ_201709'+format(i, '02d')+'_v13_r04.tab')` directly? Because `format(i, '02d')` will give you a number in string format, so there will be no need to convert it again using `str()`!